# How is from_raw_parts_mut able to transmute between types of different sizes?

Tags: rust

I am looking at the code of [`from_raw_parts_mut`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/libcore/slice.rs#L2172-L2174):

```
pub unsafe fn from_raw_parts_mut<'a, T>(p: *mut T, len: usize) -> &'a mut [T] {
    mem::transmute(Repr { data: p, len: len })
}
```

It uses `transmute` to reinterpret a `Repr` to a `&mut [T]`. As far as I understand, `Repr` is a 128 bit struct. How does this transmute of differently sized types work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mem::transmute()` does only work when transmuting to a type of the same size - so that means an `&mut[T]` slice is also the same size.

Looking at `Repr`:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Repr<T> {
    pub data: *const T,
    pub len: usize,
}
```

It has a pointer to some data and a length.  This is exactly what a slice is - a pointer to an array of items (which might be an actual array, or owned by a `Vec<T>`, etc.) with a length to say how many items are valid.

The object which is passed around as a slice is (under the covers) exactly what the `Repr` looks like, even though the data it refers to can be anything from 0 to as many `T` as will fit into memory.

In Rust, some references are not just implemented as a pointer as in some other languages.  Some types are "fat pointers".  This might not be obvious at first since, especially if you are familiar with references/pointers in some other languages!  Some examples are:

- Slices `&[T]` and `&mut [T]`, which as described above, are actually a pointer and length.  The length is needed for bounds checks. For example, you can pass a slice corresponding to part of an array or `Vec` to a function.
- Trait objects like `&Trait` or `Box<Trait>`, where `Trait` is a trait rather than a concrete type, are actually a pointer to the concrete type and a pointer to a *vtable* — the information needed to call trait methods on the object, given that its concrete type is not known.

Comment: I am bit confused. &mut is a 64bit reference (to a slice) isn't it?

Comment: No - I've updated the answer with a bit more information.

Comment: Great! Now it makes sense.